# How to remove a type string element from a list in python?

Tags: python, recursion, filtering

So basically, I have to write a code that returns the max value of an object in a list. If the list has a string, the code has to remove the string, then return the max value from the list.

This is the code that I've tried so far:

```
    for i in lst:
        if i != int:
            if i != float:
                filtered_lst = filter(lambda i: not (type(i) is str), lst)
                    if filtered_lst == []:
                        print(' ')
                    else:
                        return max(filtered_lst)
            else:
                return max(lst)
        else:
            return max(lst)
```

Which worked for the most part, however if an input is all strings (such as max_args(['5','2']), it returns an error, particularly 'max() contains an empty argument'. Any tips on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: What would be the max of an all strings number? You can call max([], default=0) to return 0 by default or any other value that you want

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect `if i != int:` to accomplish? In your own words, why is there a `for` loop in your code?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're making this problem more complicated than it has to be, you can just check for the case of an empty list and print whatever you want accordingly

```
lst = [1,2,3,"hello", 3, "world"]
fil_lst = [i for i in lst if not type(i) is str]

if len(fil_lst) == 0:
    print("Could not find max")
else:
    print(max(fil_lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

how about the below? jsut remove the strings and find the max int

```
lst = ['99', 12, '1045', 18, 55]
lst1 = [x for x in lst if isinstance(x, int)]
print(lst1)
if lst1:
   print(max(lst1))
```